# 7 segment count jump from 00 to 05

Tags: 7segmentdisplay, mplab

I'm new at coding and need some answers, I doing some mini project and I got caught in some errors I'm not sure,

I'm doing a ''photocopy'' machine and I have to code it in C under the Microchip MPLAB IDE.

so this is the requirement in my machine

1. Input On and Output does nothing
2. Input On and Increase(paper)toggle count increase
3. Input On and Decrease(paper)toggle count decrease
4. Input On,LED Copy on,and Motor runs.(7 Segment display countdown)

But here the problem, I manage to get all requirement right but for the last requirement 
after the thing have countdown and 7 segment shows 00, when I attempt to increase the count,the 7 segment increase count by random eg 00 > 5,00 > 18. what do I add in the coding line to make it increase by 1?

My last current count code is this

```
for(i=paper;i >=0;i--) //for countdown

   {

    while(SW3==1)

    LED1=1;
    Delay1KTCYx(250);
    LED1=0;
    Delay1KTCYx(250);
    M_On=1;

   }
```

what do I need to add to make sure the count doesnt jump,eg 00 > 01

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about MATLAB coding.

Comment: That code does nothing but toggle a couple variables for some `paper` count number of times.

Comment: What is Delay1KTCYx()? What is M_O? How are your displays wired? How is your problem related with the machine states? This certainly needs some clarification.

Comment: And you are missing a semicolon or a brace after while(SW3==1).

Comment: Please provide schematics and full code (not just snippets).

Comment: @LeonHeller The Code in not about MATLAB coding, it is C code written in [MPLAB](http://www.microchip.com/pagehandler/en-us/family/mplabx/) for some PIC mcu.

Comment: And even if it were implemented in matlab, switch debouncing (which is what any EE will immediately suspect as a culprit until ruled out) is entirely on topic as it is software applied to compensate for a circuit implementation issue.

Answer (score 2):

Your decrement control code above essentially debounces the input via the wait for release of the switch and blocking looped delays.

You should fix the while line-- the formatting makes it unclear .. Either

```
while(SW3==1) LED1=1;
```

.. or use curly braces if it's on another line..

A decent guess might be that your missing increment code does not work this way and switch bounce is causing multiple increments for each switch operation.

If you don't know about switch bounce- when contacts close (and to some extent when they open) the resistance does not suddenly drop from extremely high to extremely low like a clean square wave edge. The contacts are chunks of metal and they bang into each other and literally bounce open and closed a few times on the scale of milliseconds or so.

[image: http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/electronics/debounce.html]

When they open there can be mechanical vibration modes in the kHz range that cause a similar 'dirty' edge.  While you won't notice that at a human scale of perception, it's quite possible for a microcontroller to interpret the edges as many switch operations. The solutions have been covered well-- both here and elsewhere-- firmware is my preferred method but it can also be solved in hardware. One crude way is to simply ignore the switch for some tens of milliseconds after a change is detected.